# when it reached fourth tab it should not go to first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

- i am new to js
- when i click the left and right arrows the tabs circle back
- but the circle should stop. when it reached fourth tab it should not go to first.
- similarly it should happen for left arow too.
- providing my code below.

https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/mMGRbq

```
 function move(to) {
    var current = $('li.current').index();
    var total = $('.tabs .tab-link').length;
    var add;
    switch (to) {
      case 'left':
        add = -1;
        break;
      case 'right':
        add = 1;
        break;
    }
    $('.tabs li.tab-link').eq((current+add)%total).click();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function move(to) {
  var current = $('li.current').index();
  var total = $('.tabs .tab-link').length;

  var add;
  switch (to) {
    case 'left':
      current > 0 ? add = -1 : add = 0;   // don't decrement if we're already at the leftmost tab
      break;
    case 'right':
      add = 1;
      break;
  }
  $('.tabs li.tab-link').eq((current+add)).click();   // removed modulus operator to prevent wrapping back to 0
}
```

- I've added a condition to `case 'left':` to check if we're currently at the leftmost tab (index 0), and if so don't decrement any further.
- I've removed the modulus (%) operator from `$('.tabs li.tab-link').eq((current+add)).click();` to prevent the index from wrapping back to 0 when we click the right arrow with the rightmost tab activated.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code to your function to terminate early if the end tab is reached:

```
if (to === 'right' && current === (total - 1)) {
  return;
} else if(to === 'left' && current === 0) {
  return;
}
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZeNWq?editors=0001

As a side note, I implore you to think about the bigger picture when selecting DOM elements, for example in your code:

```
var current = $('li.current').index();
```

an `li` element with a class of `current` is extremely generic - if a totally unrelated `li` tag exists on your page that also has a class of `current`, your code will break. What if you had a navigation bar where the menu items also had a class of `current`? Or even if you page had 2 groups of tabs, this code wouldn't allow for it.

This is much better represented by something like:

```
var current = $('.tab-link.current').index();
```

Comment: hey I have one more doubt...I am trying to write jasmine test cases...is it possible to put everything in a method so that I can call that method for my test cases--- this click functionality $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){